# Is there anywhere near central Osaka where I can swim for free?

Tags: japan, swimming, osaka

Is there anywhere near central Osaka where I can swim for free?

I am in central Osaka at the moment and I'm trying to find a free place to swim if available. Maybe a small neighbourhood pool, private pool or even a river (I have been swimming in city rivers in several other Asian megacities already so I know it can sometimes be done).

Any advice?

Comment: Does a beach fulfil your requirement?

Comment: @KH.Lee It probably wouldn't fill the "central Osaka" part :-) Tokimeki is a bit far!

Comment: After the Japan v. Belgium game in the past World Cup, excited fans have been observed to jump into the Dotonburi River in central Osaka. Perhaps you could pretend to be celebrating...?

Comment: Typo spotted: it was the Japan v. Colombia game...

Comment: To the VTC: too broad. Is this really too broad?

Answer (score 5):

I was living in Osaka a few years ago, so I'm not sure if it's still valid, but at least back then in Sakuranomiya park there was a nice beach on the river. The beach is located approximately [here](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Waterfront+of+Osaka+Friendship/@34.702331,135.5208308,239m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x6000e6553406e2e1:0xc55bc16ee46a2fe7!2sOsaka,+Osaka+Prefecture,+Japan!3b1!8m2!3d34.6937378!4d135.5021651!3m4!1s0x6000e6d20a017223:0xc1cfcca221f08c86!8m2!3d34.702331!4d135.521378). It is fairly close to central Osaka, so it should fulfill all the requirements.

Comment: I just Googled for some photos: it seems that the water around the (artificial) beach is very shallow (to allow children to play safely). So I guess you can't swim there...?

Comment: Nice. It is a little far away from where I am staying now near Tennoji (9.7 km) but I will try to check it out some day if I can. Good advice mate. Anyone else has information about a free swimming place in Osaka?

Answer (score 3):

**There are none**. I did a throughout Google search for free swimming pools in Osaka (大阪 無料プール), and, as I have expected, there turns out to be none. There are a few cheap public pools which only charge a few hundred yen, though.

Osaka does have a harbor, but there are no beaches open for swimming within city limits. It would be likely illegal and surely hazardous to jump into the sea, since (1) the water is dirty and polluted and (2) Osaka harbor is very busy and you don't want to run into cargo ships. Same for the rivers: you aren't allowed to swim in them plus they're dirty. So, I guess that leaves you with no options here.

Comment: Thing is, not all information is indexed by Google.